# QGIS Debugging/development tools

Tags: qgis, loading

I am using the `Debugging/Development Tools` (panel) in QGIS (3.22.7) to figure out what is causing long load times, when opening a project. Most time is spent on the task `Reading external settings` (~64 sec).

Does anyone have an explanation what this is? What should I look for?

It is a relative large project ~12MB qgs-file with a large amount of layers/styling. And not much else.

[image]

Comment: Are you on a purely local system or do you have network connections/shares involved?